# How to open external url in chrome extension side panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Since Chrome version 114, it is now possible to open a side panel in Chrome. I've gone through the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/#examples) which namely shows how to use

```
chrome.sidePanel.setOptions(
  options: PanelOptions,
  callback?: function,
)
```

where [PanelOptions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/#type-PanelOptions) includes a path property to a local resource within the extension. But, I couldn't find any explanations detailing how to point to an external url. Has this been deliberately left out by Google or is there a way to point to an external resource?

Comment: There's no way. You'll have to use an iframe.